# Python: deletion of item in sys.path is undone each time I restart the interpreter

Tags: python, path, python-2.7, pythonpath

```
>>> sys.path[6]
/path/to/django
>>> sys.path.pop(6)
/path/to/django
```

Then `CTRL + D`

```
$ python

>>> sys.path[6]
/path/to/django
```

O dear...

Comment: So is the mutation/binding of any other variable. Why is this surprising?

Comment: So how do I permanently delete this item from the list?

Comment: delete it every time you start your python..

Comment: I assumed the sys module made sure that changes to that list also were adjusted in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @Bentley4 +1, so did I. On another Stack Overflow article, a user called **Sergey** said this about the subject `the change to sys.path is not permanent and only affects the current process. If you want to make a change system-wide you'll need to have a look inside the site-packages directory and do some changes. See the lnk to the site module documentation I linked above`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sys.path is populated from the externally maintained PYTHONPATH variable. Change this variable to get a permanent change when you restart python.

On unix (including Macs) when using bash it's configured most likely like this:

> export PYTHONPATH=....

And this statement is most likely hiding in your .profile or .bashrc file.

To do this in Windows you need to do something like

> SET PYTHONPATH=....

And it's probably somewhere in the system control panel - under environment.

If you want to see your current setting for PYTHONPATH, go to command (terminal) window and type `echo $PYTHONPATH` (unix) or `echo %PYTHONPATH%` (windows)

Comment: That particular PYTHONPATH I wanted to delete is not in .bashrc nor in .profile. Any other files where the pythonpath could be hiding?

Comment: /etc/profile, any associated startup scripts ... what operating system are you running?

Comment: Linux(Ubuntu). It is not in `/etc/profile.d`(there is no `/etc/profile`).

Comment: I accidently did `$ export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/django:$PYTHONPATH` instead of inserting my real path to django. Where would this be stored?

Comment: That will last only as long as your terminal window ... starting new terminal window should clear this.