# How to permanently remove value from sys.path?

Tags: python, pythonpath, sys.path

for some reason, ' ' value (empty value) was added to my sys.path array and I can't run 'setup.py install'. I can't find a way to remove it permanently. I did it through python shell:

```
sys.path.remove('')
```

and it removes it until closing the shell.
I couldn't find a good answer for permanent removing.
I did find this - [What sets up sys.path with Python, and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271494/what-sets-up-sys-path-with-python-and-when)
but I'm sure there must be a better way.

Comment: wich operating system are you using? you must remove it from the user or machine env variables, not the session ones.

Comment: Possible answer/duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11667529/8020959)

Comment: @DanielSanchez, I'm using mac.

Comment: `echo $PATH`, copy and remove undesired paths, then `export PATH=all_the_paths_you_may_need`

Comment: sys.path values are different than $PATH values...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `PYTHONPATH`

1. You can append the path to `$PATH`, and not to `$PYTHONPATH`.
2. If you insist to change the `PYTHONPATH`, in some context that is     preferable:

   do this:

   1. `Export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/username/pymodules`
   2. To make sure you are following the convention of what to append to PYTHONPATH see [What exactly should be set in PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850908/what-exactly-should-be-set-in-pythonpath).

Comment: What do you mean by 'append'? I want to remove the empty path, not appending.

Comment: Try this -->   touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile for opening the file and made change